# ldap search query with java will not work when running multiple times

Tags: java, ldap

I'm using **InitialLdapContext** in order to search a **Ldap** directory .
Though it behaves strange - if i run the search query 1-5 times in a row, its working ok, returns an answer immediately , though if i run it more than that it suddenly doesn't return , and hangs until timeout .

But if i try to do the same thing through an **Ldap Client** for exmaple **JXplorer** , it never give me a timeout .. which means there is something wrong with my code.

In addition, I'm not sure it even regards to the timeout I set to. I tried both 5sec timeout and 15sec timeout and occasionally it will wait for much more than that.

Here is the code sample:

```
Hashtable<String,Object> env = new Hashtable<>();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "my url");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "none");
            env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", "5000");
            InitialLdapContext context = new InitialLdapContext(env,null);
            NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> me = context.search("cn=*,cn=nfs,ou=policy,ou=Service,dc=doo,dc=myorg,dc=com",
                    FILTER_WITH_DEPTH.replace("replaceMe", String.valueOf(4)), getSimpleSearchControls());
            me.hasMore();
            me.close();
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If you have no relevant exception on the java side, did you check the logs of the LDAP directory when your requests crash? Do the LDAP directory properly receive them and answer them on time?

Comment: I dont have access to the ldap server.. i can only query it ..
Plus - i think the timeout does work properly in the end..